# "NameError: name 'SetNull' is not defined" error in ArcPy script?

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst, nameerror

I am trying to set a flood raster to a null value whenever it is less than 0.1 feet, but I am getting a NameError. I think I am following the SetNull documentation correctly, but can't figure out why I am getting this error. I imported arcpy at the beginning of the script. The error is on the following line of code:

```
output_raster = SetNull(raster < 0.1, raster)
```

Comment: I'm not a big fan of the practice of wildcard importing, but you either need to wildcard import from arcpy sa or explicitly include the class qualifiers to your method.

Comment: Thanks, that worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented by Vince, you either need to include the `arcpy.sa` before your `SetNull`, or do a wildcard import.

Explicit reference:

```
import arcpy
...
output_raster = arcpy.sa.SetNull(raster < 0.1, raster)
```

Wildcard import:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy.sa import *
...
output_raster = SetNull(raster < 0.1, raster)
```

Comment: `from arcpy.sa import SetNull` is also an option.